# send and receive data using ajax express node

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am new to node **Express**. I am trying to upload a file using ajax.. but I don't know the best method to do so. I have seen many tutorials.

some are written post code to the `app.js` file and some in `routes/index.js` some say directly writing in the `app.js` file is not a good approach. I wasn't able to run it using routes kindly tell me which is the better approach to do so. and how to do it.

thanks

**Ajax Call**

```
var formData = new FormData($('#cover_file_form')[0]);

$.ajax({
   // url: '/cropImg',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/cropImg',
    data: formData,
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.file_name);
    },
    error:function(dat){
        alert('error'+dat.file_name);
    }
});
```

**App.post()**

```
app.post('/cropImg',function(req,res){
    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmp_path = req.files['file_browse_cover'].path;
    //i have skipped the extra code
    es.send({file_name: req.files['file_browse_cover'].name});

}
```

Comment: I had made a repo with a bare bone MEAN setup https://github.com/drakoumel/expressnode check it out to see an MVC approach to handling your setup.

In general you should have the server.js which initialises the whole server. A route.js which has all the routings that then directs the calls to controllers.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i cannot understand where should i write the post method. if you could explain how should i call the ajax the better way in MVC approach.. i would be very thank full.. @drakoumelitos

Comment: how familiar are you with coding? sorry but this question goes beyond something people would answer in stack overflow and its better to go find some tutorials on web development in general.